# Cómo puedo enviar datos de un UINavigationController a través un relationship segue "selector"?

Tags: swift

[image: Adjunto la imagen de la relacion]

Estoy mandando datos de un view controller a un navigation controller y de ahí a un vire controller pero no encuentro como.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Con la función `performSegue` y el identificador que creaste *"SendService"*.

Comment: A mira es que tengo un view controller principal, del cual mando datos a un navigation controller, pero ya ves que el navigation controller por defaul te muestra un pantalla con la que esta relacionada a traves de un (relationship segue). el detalle en concreto es que de de ese navigation controller tengo que enviar la informaicon al otro controlado cuando se presente la vista.

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí correctamente estas usando 2 ViewControllers para 2 screens. Creaste un segue para ir de una a otra, y lo que deseas ahora es enviar información del primero al segundo.

En ese caso debes **preparar** el VC nuevo, esto se hace a través de la siguiente función -> `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) { <#code#> }`.
–normalmente viene por default comentada por Xcode, si lo creaste usando `Cocoa Touch Class`–

Obviamente deberás ingresar tu código dentro de las llaves, normalmente encontraras código como:
    `if segue.identifier == "goToResult" { let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ResultViewController destinationVC.bmiValue = calculatorBrain.getBMIValue() destinationVC.advice = calculatorBrain.getAdvice() destinationVC.color = calculatorBrain.getColor() }`

Primeramente identificas tu nueva VC en una constante `let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ResultViewController`. La parte final es la importante.

Una vez realizado empezas a pasar las propiedades como en el código de ejemplo, las cuales efectivamente ahora las sacas de tu nuevo VC, estas deberán ser **opcionales**: "`var bmiValue: String?`"; "`var advice: String?`"; "`var color: UIColor?`" porque al momento de pasar entre screens técnicamente son variables vacias pero ahí es donde entra en acción la función de arriba otorgándole sus valores para su posterior uso dentro de la nueva VC.

En caso de que quieras pasar información directamente sin usar esta función te va a dar un `error`.

Saludos!